# Issue while post from angularjs to WebAPI

Tags: angularjs, post, asp.net-web-api, cors

I am using trying to send a Post request from Angularjs to a Web Api Action method. WebApi and angular related code runes in different ports(as they are in separate projects inside a single solution). While make a post request i am getting error :

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load "API method path here". Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost:64648' is therefore not allowed access.`

The response had HTTP status code 405. my POst call is Like:

```
var data = { 'obj': 'text' };

this.PostApiCall = function (controllerName, methodName, obj) {
    result = $http.post('localhost:49551/api/' + controllerName + '/' + methodName, obj)
    .success(function (data, status) {
        alert("All right");
        result = (data);
    }).error(function () { 
        alert("Something went wrong");
    });
    return result;
};
```

It seemed that it is CORS related issue and I included `config.EnableCors();` in my WebApiConfig. Also included `[EnableCors(origins: "localhost", headers: "", methods: "")]` in my controller to allow all the requests from localhost as my post request is from localhost. Still i am getting the same error. Any idea on what is going missing?

Note: I have Http:// at all the places where localhost is, I removed Http as i am not allowed to include more than 2 links in my question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're suffering from implementation basics of $http

read this [posting-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2615-posting-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs.htm)

I'm not sure but try to use `127.0.0.1` instead

Comment: Thanks very much but when I am trying same thing with my Angular Service request and my API Controller in same project.. Everything works fine. I am able to receive the data at API method.